# Extract HTML Tag from String and "Use" it

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I am working on a project that involved purely in Vanilla JavaScript. One of the function is to preview what user have typed instantly (Using AJAX). The platform that we are using is J2EE  7, GlassFish 4.0 server.

When users attempt to format their content, they need to highlight the text they wanted to format and press a button such as "Bold", the start of highlighted area will have a string `[b]` appended and the end of highlighting area will have a string `[/b]` appended.

After user pressed the button or typed something, the ajax request will be sent to servlet and the format string will be changed to html tag such as  `<b>` `</b>`, then the server send the JSON String back to the Client side.

The JavaScript will parse the JSON using

```
 json = JSON.parse(obj)
```

After parsing, the content named "content" will be inserted to

```
 document.getElementById('preview-content').innerText = json.content;
```

Assuming the `json.content` has `abc<b> ddd </b> aaa`, after the above code is ran, the content I got is same as what it got in `json.content`, because they became a string.

How can I extract the `<b>` `</b>` from the String and "Use" it (or Format) like the what the original does?

Comment: If you send `abc [b]ddd[/b]` to the server and receive `abc <b>ddd</b>` you can put the whole string you received into `document.getElementById('preview-content').innerHTML`, no?

Comment: Using an html tag just means you need render it, unless I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
$("#preview-content").append(json.content);
```

or

```
$("#preview-content").append($(json.content));
```

or

```
document.getElementById("preview-content").innerHTML += json.content;
```

if you want to clear the content in preview-content and insert the json.content then

```
document.getElementById("preview-content").innerHTML = json.content;
```

or

```
$("#preview-content").html(json.content);
```